# Doubts spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, polymorphism, dto

I'm developing a Spring Boot MVC application and, after reading many guides and comments, I still have some doubts that I have not unmarked.

1: I do not want an anemic pattern, so I do not have a monolithic service where all the services are called each other, but these communicate only with repository instantiating entity, inside which I put the business logic, correct?

2: where to put the conversion functions entitiy-> dto? I read that someone puts them in the Controller, others in the Service, others on the same domain .. at the moment the cleanest solution and I prefer to have a Builder of the DTO that lends the entity input, okay I have contraindications?

3: polymorphism and inheritance: I have a service that composes some menu levels according to an attribute of the entity in question. I do not want to have blocks of if anywhere, I wanted to be able to put this logic in a single point, to instantiate the correct class (which I do not know a priori) and to exploit the polymorphism, how can I do? considered to involve service, entity and related logic ..

thank you so much

Comment: For the point 3 i have some ideas, but no one of theese i think is very good

Comment: The 3rd point, I don't grasp what do you want to achieve, If you could provide an example of what you intend to do, would be really helpful to understand

Comment: Controller call a service method to populate a specific level of Menu. This service istance an Entity (Entity Sport) that could be 4 different type (actually attribute class Sport) and this type follow different logic to get data to return to Controller. Now,in the service i have if ent.is_type_1() .. if ent.is_type.. etc etc...I don't want to do this, i prefer have a class that manage the right class(maybe extends Sport) to instance, then use polymorphism to call automatically right method... centralizing if code in a unique point,how can I do this to respect architecture rules MVC and OOP?

Comment: You will probably get more responses if you narrow the scope of your question. You also want to ask a specific question. You might need to split this into multiple posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions are more related to software design in general rather than specific to the Spring framework. Allowing the framework to dictate how to organize your code, has some downsides.

But to answer your questions:

1. Depending on how complex and interrelated your model is, there are different options, for the cases where there is not big interdependence between the entities in the model, the 3 layer approach is simple and good enough, but if your model is more complex, you could take a look into the concept of [Aggregates](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html), and keep the invariants hidden inside.
2. Constructing the DTO with the Entity as parameter is a good solution, whenever changes needs to be made to either the DTO or the Entity, the amount of code to maintain is not as much as with other approaches, it is not just about the conversion code, it is also about methods signatures, and all of the usages. This approach also follows the [Dependency Inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) which states that low level modules (presentation in this case) should depend on high level policies (business logic) and not the other way around. **But it is not the only valid solution, it always depends on your concrete case.**
3. If you want to return an object from your service that can be an instance of different types, there are different ways to do so, a way to do so (but not the only one, and again, the best way always depends on your concrete case):

   - For the type control, one option would be to make the method return type an interface, and then have the possible different objects that can be returned to extend that interface.
   - For the construction of the different objects, you can encapsulate it inside of the service in a private function if that is the only place you are going to use it, or if you are going to use it in more places, then you could extract it to a factory and use it as a colaborator of the service. For the construction you won't be able to avoid the `if` checks, but outside the service, once you serve the different instances, then you won't need to do more `if` checks.
   - and finally in the service return the instance that you constructed, as it implements the interface, the compiler will still be happy about it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thnak you very much.i've tryed to explain better what I mean in the 3rd point up.I hope it is 
enough, I would like to understand the correct method to encapsulate objects, reflect the pattern, take advantage of the polymorphism,maintainability,usability of the code as possible .. in general the development that I expect will be a big project, which will work more people and for a long time (in response to points 1,2, I had already guessed that there is no real solution when it comes to architecture, I was enough to have a confirmation that would confirm the correctness of what was done)

Comment: I tried to explain the best way I could, if somehow I missunderstood something or if I missed something, let me know and I'll do my best to answer again

Comment: Ok, I' think to have understood. My error was try it using generic Object return to return different classes. I don't know use of interface very weel, but I' m looking example and now i could be able to do what you write. I try and i will update you for resolution, Thank you very much

Comment: just bare in mind that the controller that consumes the service, will only be able to see the interface, with the methods that the interface declares, if your returned object has more methods, than the interface does, they will not be visible, unless you cast to your specific object, thus is the same as doing if checks. If you see yourself in that situation, reconsider another design option, because you added more complexity without gaining the benefits of polymorphism.